# What is correct way of writing code in android

Tags: android, class, button, resources

My app has lots of buttons and only one activity. So it is efficient to write all code in only one onCreate method for entire project or should i create a separate class. Please suggest what is efficient way?

Comment: entirely based on opinion, both cases work. this is a question regarding architectures or best practices which will only lead to answers based on opinions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are new to Android Development and you have to complete this app urgently, then I'll suggest to use separate function for each button in the same class, this way the code will be simple and organized.

If you have time to learn then I'll suggest to learn about the Android Architectures and try to use the MVVM architectures. To organize the code more with MVVM use the LiveData and DataBinding.

To learn more about clean coding, I'll suggest you to search "Uncle Bob" on youtube and watch a few of his lectures. His main focus is only on clean coding and I have learned alot from him.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is based on opinion, most devs would agree that using at least a little bit of Separation of Concerns is the way to go. It will make your project easily scalable and debuggable. If you are building a small app and you know it will stay small then you probably shouldn't worry.

But if you are planning on expanding the app then having "monster classes" tend to be a pain for later understanding the code, fixing errors, adding features and scaling up the app.

You can also use functions from outside the onCreate, on the Activity class, and call them on the onCreate, this makes the code more readable. For example create a function bindUI() where you set you onClickListeners, then call that function from onCreate.

Look into MVP (model-view-presenter) and MVVM (model-view-ViewModel) structures. I wrote my first ever app trying to follo an MVP structure and realized how easy it made things for me when something went wrong.